# convert List<String> to a static string if possible

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to wrap my head around `List<String>` I have a dynamicly created array `List<String> selected_tags` That I would like to convert to break apart the elements and place a "%" inbetween each element so I can use the new string in a http call.

Creat my new List :

```
public List<String> selected_tags = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Fill my List string

```
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            if (selected[i] == true){
                 selected_tags.add(tags[i]);
            }
            }
```

I then need to use selected_tags in my url

```
HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://www.mywebsite.com/scripts/getData.php?tags="+ BROKEN DOWN LIST<STRING>);
```

I would like for it to look like

```
HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://www.mywebsite.com/scripts/getData.php?tags=tag1%tag2%tag3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;   

for (String tag : selected_tags)  {
    if (!first)
        s.append("%");
    else
        first = false;

    s.append(tag);
}

String myUrlString = "tags=" + s.toString();
```

Comment: isn't bool first == true instead bool first = true?

Answer (score 3):

actually, you should have something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if(selected_tags.size() > 0) {
    sb.append(selected_tags.get(0);
    for(int i = 1 ; i < selected_tags.size(); i++) {
        sb.append("%");
        sb.append(selected_tags.get(i));
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String tag : selected_tags) {
    sb.append("%").append(tag);
}
sb.replace(0,1,"tags=");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

String prepend = "tags=";
for( String tag : selected_tags ){
    result.append(prepend).append(tag);
    prepend = "%";
}

String resultString = result.toString();
```